# Gnome Accessibility zooming and Google Docs (actually writing in browsers)

Tags: linux, gnome, accessibility

I'm Linux user since 2001 (also had my share working as a professional system administrator) but I'm a bit new to accessibility options due to degrades happened to my eye sight.

I found accessibility options in Gnome to be the best (especially Desktop zooming the one I use all the time) so I used the half screen setting on two monitors, so the left monitor is my main viewport and the right one is my magnifier.

One of its feature is writing cursor tracking, which means that the zooming lens follows cursor as I write. but I soon noticed it works only in the system text boxes (eg. gnome main menu search box, text editors, Libreoffice Write..) but NOT the web text boxes, I mean the browsers' text boxes (eg. Google Docs, Google search box, comments in facebook, this very text box of StackOverflow I'm writing in right now!)

Isn't there any fix for that? kindly note that I tested all browsers that works in gnome but they all have the same problem, and that (sorry to admit) Microsoft Windows Magnifier used to have the same problem, but they miraculously fixed it in the past few monthes (tested on google chrome / windows 10).

Thanks.